# Multivariable Taylor series expansion of $\left( \frac{\sin(x)/x}{\sin(y)/y} \right)^2$

Tags: taylor-expansion, matlab

I'm trying to find the multivariable Taylor series expansion of

$$ f(x,y) = \left( \frac{\sin(x)/x}{\sin(y)/y} \right)^2 $$

I tried to do this in Matlab (2020b), using the symbolic toolbox

```
taylor(f,[x y],[0 0],'order',6)
```

However I get an error saying it can't compute the Taylor expansion. I believe this is due to a divide by zero issue, but I'm not sure.

I can expand the numerator and denominator independently (EDIT: as pointed out, this is not the proper multi variable expansion...it was just to check if $\sin(x)/x$ was causing problems)

$$ \frac{1 - x^2/3 + 2x^4/45}{1 - y^2/3 + 2y^4/45} $$

so I'm not sure why the function expansion in Matlab doesn't work. What am I missing?

EDIT: I should note the above is an example. I'd like to have a general idea how to apply a Taylor series under these circumstances (rational function).

EDIT: The error output is

```
Error using symengine
Unable to compute a Taylor expansion.

Error in sym/taylor (line 128)
tSym = mupadmex('symobj::taylor',f.s,x.s,a.s,options);
    enter preformatted text here
```

Comment: Did you try using the `sinc` function? That is, `sinc(x)` instead of `sin(x)/x`?

Comment: $taylor(sinc(x)/sinc(y),[x,y])$ does not work either, but $taylor(sinc(x),x)$ has no trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: A better way is to consider the Taylor expansion of $g(t) := f(xt, yt)$ around $t = 0$ and then let $t=1$ in the Taylor expansion.

```
syms x y t
f = ((sin(x)/x)/(sin(y)/y))^2
f1 = subs(f,x,x*t)
f2 = subs(f1,y,y*t)
g = taylor(f2,t,0,'order',6)
g1 = expand(subs(g,t,1))
```

By the way, if you use Maple, just use

```
mtaylor(f,[x=0,y=0],7)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for. The answer seems to fit well with other examples. Never thought of evaluating elsewhere then taking a limit. Learned something new.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack But matlab should deal with this circumstance directly (Maple can deal with). I used old version of matlab. Did you use new version?

Comment: I have version 2020b, so not that old.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Yes, that is new.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The multivariable expansion is not the quotient of the univariate expansions...
$$
f(x,y) = f(0,0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) \cdot (x-0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) \cdot (y-0)+\frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,0) \cdot (x-0)^2+\cdots \right)+\cdots
$$

Comment: I wrote the univariate expressions just to see if the Matlab function $taylor$ would work with those of if they were causing trouble. I do appreciate the clarification though.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y$ does not depend on $x$, we can make the work by pieces
$$\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^2 \implies S_x=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2 x^4}{45}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{\sin (y)}{y}\right)^2 \implies S_y=1-\frac{y^2}{3}+\frac{2 y^4}{45}+O\left(y^6\right)$$

$$\frac{S_x}{S_y}=\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2 x^4}{45}+O\left(x^6\right) } {1-\frac{y^2}{3}+\frac{2 y^4}{45}+O\left(y^6\right) }$$

Now, make the long division
$$\left(1+\frac{y^2}{3}+\frac{y^4}{15}+O\left(y^6\right)\right)+x^2
   \left(-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{y^4}{45}+O\left(y^6\right)\right)+x^4
   \left(\frac{2}{45}+\frac{2 y^2}{135}+\frac{2
   y^4}{675}+O\left(y^6\right)\right)+O\left(x^6\right)$$

**Edit**

Another solution is to write
$$\left(\frac y {\sin (y)}\right)^2 \implies T_y=1+\frac{y^2}{3}+\frac{y^4}{15}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ and expand
$S_x\, T_y$ for the same result.

Comment: This looks appealing. The answer by @River LI is giving the correct solution, however if I input a higher order polynomial, it take forever to compute. What you've shown above looks like it might be more efficient, however I don't know how to implement this in Matlab. Do you know how?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack. Edited. Both solutions (River Li's and mine) are the same